# Lightning button not showing in community

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, community, custom-button

I'm trying to use a lightning button component in the community. I found this example in the documentation but its not showing in my community builder what am i missing?

```
    <aura:component>
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Submit" onclick="{! c.handleClick }" />
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming you are not just missing the button, your component may not be available to use in communities. You are missing implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" in your component.

Refer: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_lightning_community_builder.htm

Assuming you have a controller hooked up for this component else you will see Unknown controller action 'handleClick' error when you click the button

Comment: Thanks!! So simple yet so annoying when it takes so long to find the solution as this is not in the documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_button.htm

Comment: The documentation you posted shows just the component, for using a component and for the component to be available at different contexts you will have to implement the interface, take a look here to know all the available interfaces. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_interfaces.htm

Comment: most welcome :) happy i could help